# Login in PHP your account is expired show message

Tags: php, authentication

I have table fields like this

```
Username| Email | Password | Activation | Expirydate| Createddate
----------------------------------------------------------------------
niranjan|niranjan@gmail.com|12345|NULL| 2015-05-23| 2015-05-08
```

When the user login to login page my query is below it was written:

```
if (empty($error)) {
    $date = date('Y-m-d');
    $query_check_credentials = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE (Email='$Email' AND password='$Password') AND (Activation IS NULL) AND (Expirydate <= '$date')";
    $result_check_credentials = mysqli_query($dbc, $query_check_credentials);

    if (@mysqli_num_rows($result_check_credentials) == 1) {
        header('Location: course.php');
        $_SESSION = mysqli_fetch_array($result_check_credentials, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    } else {
        $msg_error = 'Either Your Account is inactive or Email address /Password is Incorrect';
    }

} else {
    echo '<div class="errormsgbox"> <ol>';
    foreach ($error as $key => $values) {
        echo '  <li>' . $values . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ol></div>';
}
```

Here I want to when user login to login page first check the errors and after that check in the table members, Expirydate <= current date I want show error message. Please help me with how can I solve this.

Comment: I think you forgot to paste your code/query in.

Comment: What is happening now?

Answer (score 0):

You probably meant to have it like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM members WHERE (Email='".$Email."' AND password='".$Password."') AND (Activation IS NULL) AND (Expirydate <= '".$date."')";
```

Assuming $Email, $Password and $date are defined earlier in the code. Also, you should make sure these variables are handled properly in regards to SQL injection.